# What do the 2 sections of the XP bar represent?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

In GT5 when you finish a race you are awarded prize money and experience. When the dialog appears to show you your experience increase there are 2 sections to the bar. The left hand portion is a solid colour; the right hand end is lighter, and fades in-and-out a bit. This happens for A-spec and B-spec XP bars as well as for the B-spec drivers' individual XP bars.

So, what do the 2 sections of the bar represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

İf I understood your question right, the light blue part is the new xp you acquired by the latest event. and their sum (solid + light parts together) is the total xp you have.

Comment: I will check tonight. I feel like the lighter bar is there before the new XP is added-on, but maybe I am imagining that. I hope it's not something so obvious.

Comment: Ok, so I just did a quick B-spec race to check this and it looks like you are right. I think the reason I didn't pick up on it is because the whole XP bar "grows" from a value of 0 to the new total XP (showing the amount you just earned as the light section); whereas I expected it to be growing from the old XP value to the new total XP value. No excuses though :)

Comment: I am glad to be of some help :)